# document styleSheets get all styles on an element with pseudo-selector

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element/5830517#5830517), I get all the element styles,

home.html

```
<div id="divClass" class="myclass">Text Here</div>
```

style.css

```
#divClass{    
   color:red; 
   background-color:black;
   float:left;
}
```

script.js

```
  function copyComputedStyle(a) {
    var sheets = document.styleSheets,
      o = {};
    for (var i in sheets) {
      var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
      for (var r in rules) {
        if (a.is(rules[r].selectorText)) {
          o = $.extend(o, css2json(rules[r].style), css2json(a.attr('style')));
        }
      }
    }
    return o;
  }

  function css2json(css) {
    var s = {};
    var pattern = /^[1-9][0-9]?$|^100$/;
    if (!css) return s;
    if (css instanceof CSSStyleDeclaration) {
      for (var i in css) {
        if (css[i].toLowerCase) {
          // Some of the key value pairs were vice versa, so try to make them in order!
          // Ex:    0:flex-grow;  0:flex-shrink;  --------> flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0;
          // End
          if (pattern.test(css[i])) {
            s[css[css[i]].toLowerCase()] = css[i];
          } else {
            s[css[i].toLowerCase()] = css[css[i]];
          }
        }
      }
    } else if (typeof css == 'string') {
      css = css.split('; ');
      for (var i in css) {
        var l = css[i].split(': ');
        s[l[0].toLowerCase()] = l[1];
      }
    }
    return s;
  }

console.log(copyComputedStyle($("#divClass")));
```

it returns an Object

```
{
   background-color: "black",
   color: "red",
   float: "left",
   left: ""
}
```

Now, when I add any pseudo-selector `hover` or `before` and `after` to this div, the `copyComputedStyle` does not log the added styles and return the same style as before!

```
#divClass{    
   color:red; 
   background-color:black;
   float:left;
}
#divClass:hover{    
   color:blue; 
}
```

How can I overcome that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when using `.is()`, especially when `#divClass` is not matching to `#divClass: hover`

One solution is to use indexOf to make sure you find the selector that matches the element ID:

*Change this:* `if (a.is(rules[r].selectorText)) {`

*for this:* `if (rules[r].selectorText && rules[r].selectorText.indexOf(a.attr('id')) != -1) {`

If you change that line in your code it will return something like this:

```
{
   background-color: "black",
   color: "blue",
   float: "left",
   left: ""
}
```

It is because there are duplicate `color` properties in the object and the latter predominates, personally what I would do is have an object with the styles per selector grouped:

```
 function copyComputedStyle(a) {
    var sheets = document.styleSheets,
        o = {},
        objrules = [];

    for (var i in sheets) {
      var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
      
      for (var r in rules) {
        if (rules[r].selectorText && rules[r].selectorText.indexOf(a.attr('id')) != -1) {
          o = $.extend({},css2json(rules[r].style));
          objrules.push({'selector' : [rules[r].selectorText], 'style' : o});
        }
      }
    }

    return objrules;
  }

  function css2json(css) {
    var s = {};
    var pattern = /^[1-9][0-9]?$|^100$/;

    if (!css) return s;

    if (css instanceof CSSStyleDeclaration) {
      for (var i in css) {
        if (css[i].toLowerCase) {
          // Some of the key value pairs were vice versa, so try to make them in order!
          // Ex:    0:flex-grow;  0:flex-shrink;  --------> flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0;
          // End
          if (pattern.test(css[i])) {
            s[css[css[i]].toLowerCase()] = css[i];
          } else {
            s[css[i].toLowerCase()] = css[css[i]];
          }
        }
      }
    } else if (typeof css == 'string') {
      css = css.split('; ');
      for (var i in css) {
        var l = css[i].split(': ');
        s[l[0].toLowerCase()] = l[1];
      }
    }
    
    return s;
  }

console.log(copyComputedStyle($("#divClass")));
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, but there is a little problem -->  `objrules.selector` get the correct selectors but  `objrules.style`  does not have any content! it's blank!

Comment: Yes I got it.... just change `o = $.extend({},css2json(rules[r].selectorText, rules[r].style));` to `o = $.extend({},css2json(rules[r].style));`. thanks a ton!

Comment: Yes, I was just going to write that hahaha, I'm glad it was helpful

Comment: so sorry a quick question, how can i just select my own style `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />`, because i have `bootstrap` and font `awesome` CDN links???

Comment: The sheets are stored in the sheets variable, I see that it also includes the bootstrap styles, maybe I would use something like `sheets[i] .href.indexOf ("bootstrap")` to capture the styles from the CDN, or there is a faster way